# Bluebird: Promise has no method 'spread'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to chain series of promises using Bluebird's `spread` method. When I run it, it throws the following error:

```
Object #<Promise> has no method 'spread'
```

Code below:

```
{
  new : function( req, next ) {
    var packet = req.body;
    var new_doc = { some obj data };

    switch (packet.event.name) {
      case "liked":
        this._create(req, new_doc )
          .spread( this._update.user )
          .spread( this._update.chirp ) // omitted from this question
        break;
      // other cases...
    };
  },
  _create: function( req, new_doc ) {

    return model_interaction.create( new_doc, function (err, interaction) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      return [ req, interaction ];
    });

  },
  _update: {
    user: function ( req, interaction ) {

      req.user._interactions['_' + interaction.event.name].push(interaction._id);
      req.user.save();

      return [ req, interaction ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Using version bluebird version 2.9.34

Comment: Well, afaik mongo does not return Bluebird promises…

Answer (score 0):

I do not think `_create` is returning a promise object, if it does, I am not sure why it has a node style callback, I would change it to:

```
_create: function( req, new_doc ) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      model_interaction.create( new_doc, function (err, interaction) {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve([ req, interaction ]);
      });
  });
},
```